# Имена файлов c одним подчёркиванием в Python

Tags: python-3.x

Копаюсь в папках разных модулей и заметил одну особенность. Какие-то файлы написаны с одним подчёркиванием, а какие-то без них. В чём особенность? Знаю, что есть такая "договорённость о приватных переменных" в классах. Но раньше не встречал такое. Для чего это нужно? Тоже для подсказок о том, что файлы приватные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно автор(ы) таким образом подсказывают себе на каком уровне файл(код в нем) типа иерархия.

Comment: @MrP я бы предположил, что не для иерархии, а чтобы не было конфликта с пакетами с такими же именами, типа https://pypi.org/project/lxml/, https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/. Возможно это обертки над этими пакетами.